# Control selected items of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of `Client`:

`ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();`

These clients are shown in a list, and the user can "select" one or more clients. That means that every client can be selected, or not selected, and there is no need to store this value out of the screen where the list is shown. I want to keep this user's choice to work with it (like setting a checkbox in the list, for example) but I was wondering what is the best way to do it. What I've tried:

- Add a boolean field `selected` to the class `Client`. I don't like this option since selected is not an original property of `Client` and it has not meaning on it.
- Extends `Client` into `SelectableClient`, and add the boolean field `selected`.
- Have a secondary array (or ArrayList, or whatever) which controls the selected status.
- Use a `Map<boolean, Client>` structure, but I'm not sure about this option since I add and remove clients from the arrayList.

What of this options is the most efficient and easiest to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `Set<Client>` (such as a `HashSet<Client>`) and add the selected clients to this set.

This avoids adding a field to `Client` that doesn't really belong in that class.

Note that if you're using a `JList` for instance, you can use `ListModel`/`ListSelectionModel` directly. (You don't need to create / maintain a data structure for holding the selected clients yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

> Add a boolean field selected to the class Client

As you've pointed out already, the selected state is not a property of the client, but of the user. If you have multiple users, one user may have selected a client, while another user has not. That's why the selection should be kept in the user's scope.

Using a `Set<Client>`, as it was already suggested, seems like the best data structure as it avoids duplicates and thus clients can safely be deselected using `remove()`.

> Extends Client into SelectableClient

This approach has the same problem, the selection state is modelled as property of the client, not the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a new generic class sth like this:

```
class SelectableItem<T> {
    private T item;
    private boolean selected;

    public SelectableItem(T item, boolean selected) {
         ....
    }
    // getters setters
}
```

and create array or set of this type. That way you'll have only one extra class, and you can reuse it later for other use cases

Comment: This introduces some unfortunate invariants though, because each client in the gui must have *precisely* one corresponding `SelectableItem` object. (And checking if a client is selected becomes a linear operation too.)

Comment: Implementing features like this always have some drawbacks. linear check if single client is select and linear time when rendeing in this case, to logn for single customer check and nlogn for rendering when using treeset to keep selected customer. and what about issue with precisely one corresponding selectableItem object ?